# How to refactor function parameters for this logic: "param 2 is only needed if param 1 is true"?

Tags: refactoring

I have to following functions:

```
public enum class SetMinMaxMode
{
    Auto, // min and max is set based on the channel data
    Manual
};

generic<typename T> where T : System::ValueType
void SetData(array<T>^ data)
{
    SetData(data, SetMinMaxMode::Auto, Double::MinValue, Double::MaxValue);
}

generic<typename T> where T : System::ValueType
void SetData(array<T>^ data, SetMinMaxMode minMaxMode, Double minValue, Double maxValue)
{
    //
}
```

The parameter minValue and maxValue is only used when parameter minMaxMode is SetMinMaxMode::Manual.

If someone writes function like this:

```
SetData(data, SetMinMaxMode::Auto, desiredMinValue, desiredMaxValue);
```

Then he might not know that the last two parameters are not going to be used.

My questions is, is there any way to refactor so that someone will never need to supply unnecessary parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function that doesn't take SetMinMaxMode at all.

```
SetDataAuto(data);
```

so you either call the one with min/max or you call the one with auto.

Your other function would be:

```
SetDataManual(data, min, max);
```

Comment: Yes, using different function name would be a solution. But if you think how to implement those two functions, there still needs a "expanded" function taking all the parameters, like SetDataCore(data, mode, min, max).

Comment: SetDataAuto can just call SetDataManual with the two additional parameters. `SetDataAuto(Data){ SetDataManual(data, 1, 2); }`

Comment: sorry there might be a confusion here. SetDataAuto will calc the min and max based on the data, the calculated min and max is only known at run time. I guess I could do something like `SetDataAuto(data) { double min, max; FindMinMax(data, min, max); SetDataManual(data, min, max); }`. But what if I really want to have a **core** function that takes all the parameters?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant for SetDataAuto.  In this case the *core* function is already SetDataManual.  SetDataAuto is simply a wrapper for it.